# How to solve error when install react-animated-3d-card

Tags: reactjs

When I want react-animated-3d-card, I get an error with Npm when I install it

[image]

How can i fix this errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package `react-animated-3d-card` requires react version 16 as stated in the error log. The only way to use it in your project is to downgrade react to version 16. Your current react version is 18.